# Is it necessary to allocate multiple channels to an access point at the same time?

Tags: wireless, digital-communications, telecommunications

I need to ask a question about practical issue in channel sharing in wireless communication as follows.

Let we have a set of 4 unlicensed networks with access points denoted as, \$\{N_1, N_2, N_3, N_4\}\$.
Let we have 2 channels (frequency slots) available to allocate to the networks, denoted as \$C_1\$, \$C_2\$.

Let 3 networks' APs, \$\{N_1, N_2, N_3\}\$ demand one channel for a certain time duration to operate while network 4's AP, \$N_4\$ demands two channels to operate for a certain duration.

My channel sharing system properly schedule them in Time-domain.

The system allocates the required number of channels to these APs. However, in order to satisfy some other allocation constraints, my system may schedule the AP \$N_4\$ in different time-window in \$C_1\$ and \$C_2\$.

For example, system may schedule \$N_4\$ on \$C_1\$ in time window \$T_1\$ while on \$C_2\$ in time window \$T_2\$.

Now someone make an objection that

"it is not practical that you schedule a network in different time window." He said, "if a network is allocated multiple channels then it needs all those channels at the same time to operate. We cannot schedule the network in different time window"

I am wondered that, is this objection true in the perspective of any of the network technology like WiFi, WiMax, WRAN etc.? I mean is it necessary that an AP is to be allocated all the desired channels in the same time window?

If there is no such compulsion can you please tell me some reference so that I can use that reference in the argument.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

In short answer that is correct, if a network is allocated multiple channels then it needs all those channels at the same time to operate. We cannot schedule the network in different time window.
You are using the basic concept of OFDM where in you divide your channel into multiple frequency and operate you're communication system in those channels, Note that when you divide your channel in frequencies you're basically extending the amount of time to transmit the same amount of symbols,hence while using N4 AP it is better for performance reasons to alot both the channels at the same time otherwise you would have a worse performance.
Also in your scenario i would suggest not dividing the channels at all you could use CDMA for the N1,N2,N3 for T1 and use N4 at T2 this way you'll use the maximum spectral efficiency and you're bandwidth wont be idle.
Which is a combination of TDMA and CDMA(Time Division Multiple access)